# Eclipse CDT highlights static_assert(cond) as syntax error

Tags: c++, c++11, eclipse-cdt, c++17

Eclipse CDT complains that the following is syntactically wrong, although it compiles fine with `g++-7 -std=c++17`:

```
static_assert(std::is_pod<T>::value);
```

while it doesn't complain on the following:

```
static_assert(std::is_pod<T>::value, "not a POD");
```

I realize that the prior to C++17 `static_assert` required a second message parameter.
I'm curious if Eclipse could be configured to recognize the first form? (A workaround is of course to use the C++11 form.)

On a side note, g++ 7.1 is OK with both forms, even with `-std=c++11`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse CDT does not yet have any C++17 support, so it does not recognize this form of `static_assert`.

You could work around this by defining the following macro in your code:

```
#define static_assert(cond) static_assert(cond, "")
```

If your compiler objects to this, you can condition it on the `__CDT_PARSER__` macro, so that only CDT sees it, not your compiler:

```
#ifdef __CDT_PARSER__
  #define static_assert(cond) static_assert(cond, "")
#endif
```

If you prefer to apply this workaround without modifying your source files, you could also define this macro in `Project Properties | C/C++ General | Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. | GNU C++ | CDT User Setting Entries`.